# Sidekiq UI : Internal Server Error production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq, sidetiq

I am trying to run Sidekiq UI in production mode, though the workers are running fine but sometimes they crash and hence I wanted to look at the UI to either restart them or see whats the issue. This only is a problem in production mode, the dev mode works flawlessly!

But when I access /sidekiq UI I always end up getting a Internal Server Error and I can't seem to get any backtrace either in my log/sidekiq.log or log/production.log in my rails app.

What's the best way to get this working or atleast get me the backtrace!

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'sidekiq', '0.7.0' #I am using sidetiq for scheduling
gem 'sidekiq-middleware', '0.3.0'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
```

**Command to start sidekiq**

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production
```

**Sidekiq log has this output always (if any helpful)**

```
Can't link Sidetiq::Actor::Handler. Sidekiq::Manager not running. Retrying in 5 seconds ...
Can't link Sidetiq::Actor::Handler. Sidekiq::Manager not running. Retrying in 5 seconds ...
Can't link Sidetiq::Actor::Handler. Sidekiq::Manager not running. Retrying in 5 seconds ...
DEBUG: [Sidetiq] Can't link Sidetiq::Actor::Clock. Sidekiq::Manager not running. Retrying in 5 seconds ...
Sidetiq] Lock: sidetiq:MyAwesomeWorker:lock
[Sidetiq] Enqueue: MyAwesomeWorker (at: 1458064200.0) (last: 1458064140.0)
Sidetiq] Unlock: sidetiq:MyAwesomeWorker:lock
```

Answer (score 1):

So finally I was able to get an answer to my question.

I was using Unicorn for my child processes and they weren't able to access redis server as it had a AUTH attached!